# Truly Portable Git

Tags: git, bash, cygwin, portable-applications

I'm trying to create a fully portable version of git on a USB drive with it's own SSH keys and I want it to work regardless of the drive letter windows gives it. I've installed portable git and most of it works. The problem I have is setting the `$HOME` to be dynamic I want it to point to `/DRIVELETTER/PortableApps/PortableGit` so when I generate and use my SSH keys it will go to `/DRIVELETTER/PortableApps/PortableGit/.ssh/`

Right now `$HOME` is `/` and it makes the default path for ssh generation `//.ssh/id_rsa` which doesn't exist. I have found site that say "SET IT TO `/e/bla/bla/bla/`" but that doesn't work if the drive letter is `J`.

I have not found any good guides to setting up truly portable git.

Thanks for any help
Munchies

Comment: You are insane. Flash drives have a limited write capability before they are unusable. around 100,000 writes per byte. Git will destroy that thing in no time. I hope you are ready for lots of errors to spring up... lol now if you are using "real hardware" you might be getting somewhere... This is not a programming question you need to consult your portable git developers and your cygwin documentation for configuring the environment to your own specifications.

Comment: @Triston: "You want to make a virus box a development box" - what?

Comment: Trust me. I'm way more comfortable on in a Unix style command line environment, however that is not an option at the moment. I need something to git on the go on windows. Also I'm Okay if this thumb drive only lasts a year.

Comment: @TristonJ.Taylor I didn't understand what you mean by that either. Also, it's fairly off topic in this situation.

Comment: Ahh, I see... Feel free to flag/downvote. Just trying to be helpful. I can't tell you how many hours of work I have lost over the years because of microsoft. `uptime:
 17:37:04 up 3 days, 12:42` This is the uptime on my laptop. UNIX Systems are the only way to go for mission critical applications. I rebooted for system upgrades by the way.

Comment: Can't you try to install your git portable version using a Unix system ? Wouldn't that be more simple to have a path like /dev/sdb1/... instead of your actual path ? Just for the installation, you know. Btw @TristonJ.Taylor your uptime has nothing to do here I guess. Though I agree, working on arch is better than working on windows. (=> But this has nothing to do here)

Comment: I'm ultimately working to program microcontrollers with microC for AVR I looked to find linux compliers but management have suspended that project. It really sucks. Also, I would like to work on a linux computer and just load onto a windows virtual machine to flash the program to the microcontroller. Right now I'm bouncing between computer labs at the college and trying to work as a team.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a batch file first do

```
for /F "delims=\: usebackq" %%i in (`cd`) do SET USB_DRIVE=%%i
```

then the rest of the time (in batch files) use `%USB_DRIVE%` instead of d: or 
whatever letter it is.

Comment: Thanks. From that I used `HOME=/$(echo $USB_DRIVE | awk '{print substr($0,0,1)}')/PortableApps/PortableGit` to strip the ':' from the drive letter and it works. Thanks very much